# React component's Material UI theme not scoped locally to Shadow DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, material-ui, shadow-dom

## Intro

I am building a Chrome Extension that renders a React component using the Content script. The React component is a toolbar that has sub-tools for users to use while browsing the page. I am using Material UI as my component library and styling solution for the toolbar and all of its other child components, popups, etc.

## What Works

Injecting the root React component into the page works just fine using a div, "Extension" as a mountNode.

**content.js** (Chrome Content Script)

```
var app = $('<div id="Extension" style="position: fixed; display: block; bottom: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100vw; height: 48px; background: grey; z-index: 99999"></div>')
app.prependTo('body');
render(<App />, document.getElementById('Extension'))
```

**app.js** (Main React Component)

`Material UI` is also able to generate a new styles object and apply the css styling to the child components on the page. So this is all good

(source)

```
const styles = {
  root: {
    display: "block",
    color: "red",
  },
};
```

(generated)

```
.App-root-1 {
  color: red;
  display: block;
}
```

## The Problem

Because I am using a content script in chrome, sites like Facebook with general css selectors try to override the styling in `Material UI`. It would also be possible for css attributes to leak from the the React toolbar into the main page.

## Halfway Solution

My current solution is to use `react-shadow` to scope the styling around the React component and keep it isolated from the rest of the page.

```js
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

import ShadowDOM from 'react-shadow';
import ToolBar from './ToolBar'

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: '#ef5350',
    },
    type: 'light'
  },
  status: {
    danger: 'orange',
  },
});

const styles = {
  root: {
    display: "block",
    color: "red",
  },
};

class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
  
      this.state = { open: false }
  }

  render () {
    const { classes } = this.props;

    return (
      <ShadowDOM>
          <div id="Toolbox">
              <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                  <ToolBar />
              </MuiThemeProvider>
          </div>    
      </ShadowDOM>
    )
  }
};

App.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(App)
```

When I did this, the generated theme from 'Material-UI' does not apply to the toolbar, and I am left with the default inline styling applied to the "Extension" div (defined above, **content.js**).

The theme is generated using `createMuiTheme(options)` from the `material-ui` package:

This function is successful, and the theme is applied  using:

```
<MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
```

I can confirm that `createMuiTheme(options)` & `<MuiThemeProvider/>` 
 are working because the theme's generated stylesheets are added as the last tags in the page's `<head>` tag, as seen here in the image:

[`<head>` tag contains MUI generated styles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuxFn.png)

## What I Need to Happen

Because my React toolbar element is inside #shadow-root, it is unable to recieve styling from the MUI generated classes, because they are contained in the main `<head>` tag, in the main DOM tree. I believe when `<MuiThemeProvider/>` is rendered, it appends its provided stylesheets to the top of the **main** DOM tree, **NOT** the ***#shadow-root*** (where they need to be so that the styles apply locally). See the image below:

[MUI Stylesheets in `</head>`, but they need moved to `#shadow-root`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXomC.png)

So I am looking for a solution to have the stylesheets generated by Material UI to be placed under the #shadow-root for them to apply correct styling on my React toolbar component.

1.) Is there any way to have `<MuiThemeProvider/>` scope to the shadow DOM, or prefix the classnames with something like :host?

2.) Is there a way to lock down the #shadow-root created with `react-shadow`, so that when `<MuiThemeProvider/>` appends the stylesheets, they are forcefully appended to the shadow root?

3.) I am still very inexperienced with React, Javascript, and creating Chrome Extensions. Perhaps I am missing a very simple solution already?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: See [How to really isolate stylesheets in the Google Chrome extension?](//stackoverflow.com/q/12783217)

Comment: @wOxxOm, thanks for the reply. Much of the topic mentions isolation using iFrames, but I have already tried this. I have UI elements that need to display outside the bounds of a frame. There are other topics discussed though, that may help.

I have been looking at `material-ui`'s CSS in JS article. It may be possible to set a custom JSS insertion point for the JSS Provider in the #shadow-root.
---

[Material UI - CSS in JS](https://material-ui.com/customization/css-in-js/#material-ui-39-s-styling-solution)

Comment: @BradenPreston have you faound a solution to this? I'm trying to achieve the same things.

Comment: @BradenPreston bro, did you discovered how to solve this? I'm having the exact same problem...

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue packaging my web application for integration with another framework, which required my React app to be exported as a Web Component. After struggling for a while with libraries like `react-jss` and having no luck, I finally came across [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56516753/3896566) by [@shawn-mclean](https://stackoverflow.com/users/400861/shawn-mclean) this morning. I had seen your question while banging my head against my desk and wanted to pass on what worked for me.

In summary, I first had to create the Web Component

**WCRoot.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { StylesProvider, jssPreset } from '@material-ui/styles';
import { create } from 'jss';
import App from './App';

class WCRoot extends HTMLElement {

    connectedCallback() {
        const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
        const mountPoint = document.createElement('span');
        // first we need to store a reference to an element INSIDE of the shadow root        
        const reactRoot = shadowRoot.appendChild(mountPoint);

        // now we use that saved reference to create a JSS configuration
        const jss = create({
            ...jssPreset(),
            insertionPoint: reactRoot
        });

        // finally we need to wrap our application in a StylesProvider
        ReactDOM.render(
            <StylesProvider jss={jss}>
                <App />
            </StylesProvider>,
            mountPoint);
    }
}
customElements.define('wc-root', WCRoot);
```

Next, I set my `index.js` to render `<wc-component></wc-component>` instead of `<App />`:

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
// eslint-disable-next-line
import WCRoot from './WCRoot';

ReactDOM.render(<wc-root></wc-root>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

One thing which surprised me is that we don't need to modify the `MuiThemeProvider` at all...it just grabs the existing JSS context provided by the `StylesProvider`. I believe you should be able to modify `content.js` to look something like the following:

**content.js**

```
var app = $('<div id="Extension" style="position: fixed; display: block; bottom: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100vw; height: 48px; background: grey; z-index: 99999"></div>')
app.prependTo('body');

var shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
var mountPoint = document.getElementById('Extension');
var reactRoot = shadowRoot.appendChild(mountPoint);

// see code blocks above for the import statements for `create` and `jssPreset`
var jss = create({
    ...jssPreset(),
    insertionPoint: reactRoot
});

render(
    <StylesProvider jss={jss}>
        <App />
    </StylesProvider>,
    mountPoint);
```

Comment: For future readers, this works without creating a custom WebComponent

Comment: This works fine for MUI components that render in the shadow DOM subtree, but those that use portals (like Dialog) will not get styled. Ref: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/17473