# How can I wrap a material-ui react component to a Web Component without losing the styles?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, web-component

I'm developing a wrapper to transpile React components into Web Components. What do I need to apply the styles when the components are rendered in the shadow DOM?.

I am trying to wrap a material-ui react component (Button) in a Web Component, however when I attach the component to the shadow DOM the styles are not applied.

//Wrapper

```
import ReactDOM,{ render } from 'react-dom';

import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

class ButtonWrapper extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
    connectedCallback() {
        const mountPoint = document.createElement('span');
        this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' }).appendChild(mountPoint);
       ReactDOM.render(
            <Button variant="contained" color="primary">
                Material Button
            </Button>
            , mountPoint);  
    }
}

customElements.define('button-material-wrapper', ButtonWrapper);
```

//HTML

```
<button-material-wrapper></button-material-wrapper>
```

//Webpack.config

```
...
module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.js$/,
                    use: {
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                        options: { presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'] }
                    }
                },
                {
                    test:/\.(s*)css$/,
                    use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
                }
            ]
        }
....
```

Expected output:
The material-ui button is correctly rendered

Actual output:
The material-ui button is corectly rendered as a child node of the shadow-root but the material styles are not applied.

Answer (score 0):

In webpack, style-loader helps you to add the style to global document style. But web component can not access the style(including the global material style) outside shadow DOM which result in your Actual output.
One solution I found is to use **css-to-string-loader** to import the string of the scss of material component manually, and then add it to the style of current shadow DOM by hand.

// Webpack.config

```js
{
    test: /.*\.scss$/,
    use: ['css-to-string-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
},
```

// In Web Component (connectedCallback)

```js
const style = document.createElement('style');
const style.innerHTML = require('@material/xxxx.scss');
const head = document.createElement('head');
head.appendChild(style);
this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' }).appnedChild(head)
```

In my opinion, it's not elegant at all, looking forward to a better solution.

Comment: Here a solution:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54430119/how-to-mount-styles-inside-shadow-root-using-cssinjs-jss/56516753#56516753](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54430119/how-to-mount-styles-inside-shadow-root-using-cssinjs-jss/56516753#56516753)